# Show an element with sliding the ranger element slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, geometry

I want to show a circle with an input type when the range element slider is sliding by user & when user stopped to sliding the circle and input hide together.
I wrote a code to show the value of range slider and it should keep working in my code.
The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        function updateTextInput(val){
            document.getElementById('textInput').value = val;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="circle-text">
        <input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
    </div>
    <input id="range" type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" 
    onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In its current form your question/request is quite unclear. The closest interpretation is you want to show the value of the range input inside a  circular element positioned in relation with the range knob on `mousedown` (while input is clicked and dragged) and you want to stop showing this element on `mouseup`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide the circle and input in mouse up and show them again in mouse down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, the following additions to your code should achieve the behaviour that you're after:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #textInput {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="circle-text">
        <input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
    </div>
    <input id="range" type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" 
    oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);">

    <script>
        // Select DOM elements
        var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('range');
        var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');

        // Add event listeners
        rangeSlider.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
            textInput.style.visibility = "hidden" ;
        });

        rangeSlider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
            textInput.style.visibility = "visible" ;
        });

        function updateTextInput(val){
            textInput.value = val;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```